# Construct a time series dataset out of irregularly changing data

Tags: r, time-series

I have a dataset that represents a central bank parameter (width of LAF corridor for the Indian Central Bank, the RBI) for the period from 04/2001 to 03/2011. Now, this dataset looks like this :

| 27/04/2001 - 29/04/2001         | 225  |
| 30/04/2001 - 27/05/2001         | 200  |
| 28/05/2001 - 06/06/2001         | 225  |
| 07/06/2001 - 04/03/2002         | 200  |
.....

I would like to convert this into a time series dataset with an LAF width entry for each day of the year from the time period under study (04/2001 - 03/2011). How do I convert this into an appropriate time series ?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose your data is in a df with two columns like this?:

```
period <- c("27/04/2001 - 29/04/2001", "30/04/2001 - 27/05/2001", 
        "28/05/2001 - 06/06/2001", "07/06/2001 - 04/03/2002")
values <- (c(225, 200, 225, 200))
df <- data.frame(period, values)
```

Then I add columns for the starting day end ending of each period with the `substr` command, and add the total number of days in that period (comes in handy to check for completeness)

```
df$start <- as.Date(substr(df$period,1,10), "%d/%m/%Y")
df$end <- as.Date(substr(df$period,14,23),  "%d/%m/%Y")
df$nodays <- df$end-df$start+1
```

Next I create a new df with in one column all the dates that exist in the original df, with the corresponding LAF-value.

```
LAF_date <- NULL
LAF_value <- NULL
for (i in 1:dim(df[1])){
    tmp_date <- seq.Date(df$start[i],df$end[i], by="days")
    LAF_date <- append(LAF_date, tmp_date)
    tmp_value <- rep(df$values[i], length(tmp_date))
    LAF_value <- append(LAF_value, tmp_value)
    }        

new_df <- data.frame(as.Date(LAF_date), LAF_value )
```

There will proabably be a faster way, but today I lose my virginity on answering a question on Stackoverflow (blush, blush). Hope you can use it.